# Looking for Hungarian voters list around 1931

Tags: 1930s, hungary, voter-lists

I am trying to track my grandfathers movements at the beginning of the 1930s and i wanted to check if he was listed in the 1931 voters list for the Hungarian parliament elections but i didn't manage to find any online record of it.

Does anyone knows if such a thing exists online or if it can only be found in the local county archive?